# Extract cursor size via WinAPI (Windows 10)

Tags: java, c++, swing, winapi, windows-10

I need to extract the cursor image for using it in my swing application (Java).

Firstly, I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739870/extract-cursor-image-in-java/740528), modified code snippet from an answer, and got this [sandbox application](https://pastebin.com/uDvH3HL7).

Shortly, it gets cursor image via JNA and WinAPI, then shows this image on JFrame and sets custom cursor for this frame.

In most cases, this code works correctly and suits my tasks. But then I found that *when the user changes the cursor's size or color*([Windows 10 feature](https://pureinfotech.com/change-mouse-pointer-size-windows-10/)), the program extracts an invalid cursor image that matches the original cursor neither in color nor in size.

*When the user has standard cursor:*

[image]

*When the user has e.g. pink cursor then bigger than standard one:*

[image]

After this situation, I decided to do the same sandbox application, but via C++ and WinAPI. I used answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469538/winapi-get-mouse-cursor-icon), but solved only troubles with color.

[image]

I think the main bottleneck is that `GetSystemMetrics` function returns default cursor size (32x32) and it doesn't change after the cursor's size changing. I found some proves for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699666/how-do-i-know-the-size-of-a-hcursor-object), but I'm not sure.

So my question is:

*How can I get the real size of cursor?*

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get mouse cursor icon VS c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509951/how-to-get-mouse-cursor-icon-vs-c)

Comment: @ÖöTiib in my cpp sandbox I did the same stuff, but it doesn't handle size changes of the cursor. The cursor is always 32x32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Rita Han - MSFT for giving the initial point to start searching.

You can get a real cursor size in two ways:

1. The first way is mentioned before: we need to get value from registry value `CursorBaseSize` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors`.
2. The second way was found [here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/ru-RU/62f1e3ab-d59a-4267-ba9f-cc569b979640/how-to-get-displayed-sizes-of-mouse-cursor-on-windows-10-in-program?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues): we can get cursor size multiplier form registry value `CursorSize` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Accessibility` and then calculate the cursor size yourself. It can be done somehow like this: `newHeight = cursorHeight + (multiplier - 1) * (cursorHeight / 2);` where `cursorHeight` is value from `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCURSOR)` and `multiplier` is value from the registry. The cursor real width value will be the same as `newHeight`. *All values are `unsigned long`* if we use C++.`

Both methods of finding the size lead to the same result.

If you need to find to get cursor real size value from the registry *in Java*, you can use `Advapi32Util` class from `JNA-platform`:

```
        // Read an int (& 0xFFFFFFFFL for large unsigned int)
        int baseSize = Advapi32Util.registryGetIntValue(
                WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Control Panel\\Cursors", "CursorBaseSize");
```

Answer (score 5):

> I think the main bottleneck is that GetSystemMetrics function returns
> default cursor size (32x32) and it doesn't change after the cursor's
> size changing.

When user change cursor size via Settings. System Settings will update this change to registry value `CursorBaseSize` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors`.

You can get notification when change happens via [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange?redirectedfrom=MSDN) or [`SetWinEventHook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) ([`EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants), [`OBJID_CURSOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/object-identifiers)).

Then read `CursorBaseSize` register value to get new size and get other information using [`GetIconInfoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-geticoninfoexw) to creates a cursor having the specified size. ([`CreateCursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createcursor))

More references: [How can I get notified when the cursor changes?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151116-00/?p=92091)